# How to use neo4j effectively for serious, repeatable analysis over time

Tags: neo4j

New to neo4J and love the browser for exploratory work.  But, I'm unsure of how to best use it to achieve, for lack of a better term, real work. Consider a sample project involving:

- Importing 4 different CSV files
- Creating appropriate relationships between nodes
- Doing a variety of complex queries to derive data that I'll export for statistical analysis using another program.

I need to be able to replicate the project in the future, as well as adding new data, calculating different derived data, etc. I also need to be able to share the code so others can extend/verify it.

For non-relational data, I'd use something like R, Stata or SAS.  While each allow interactive exploration like the neo4J browser, I'd never use that for serious analysis.  Instead, I'd save a file or files of commands that I could modify and rerun whenever I needed to.

Neo4j's browser doesn't seem to support any of this functionality. Unless I am missing something, it doesn't even allow one to save a "session" along the lines of a iPython/Jupyter notebook. I know that there is a neo4-shell, but especially since they have dropped it from the standard desktop installation (and gotten rid of the console), I feel like I must be doing something wrong--or at least contrary to the designers' intent--if I can't do serious work in the browser.  Clearly, lots of people are.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  How does one best develop an extensive, replicable project over time with neo4j? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can take your pick of [several officially-supported language drivers](https://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/) to integrate neo4j into basically any other project structure, including Jupyter notebooks. I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "serious work", or where you got the idea that people did lots of it in the browser, but you are definitely able to save the results of a query from the browser in a variety of formats (pictures of the bubbles, result rows in a CSV, JSON response) if your prefer to work that way, or you can pipe data very efficiently into another language and manage it there. I don't see why they would re-create presentation and/or project management tools when there are already so many good ones out there.

Comment: Thank you.  Based on your answer, would it be right to understand that the "norm" would be to use, say, Python and embed Cypher in `session.run()` statements rather than running Cypher from the neo4j-shell? Either seems technically straight-forward. Running Cypher directly seems more direct, but neo4j's (apparent) downplaying of the shell seems to suggest that doing so is not their vision for most people. If so, they probably have good reasons--I'm just trying to avoid swimming upstream out of naiveté.  Thank you again.

Comment: I don't think I can say what the norm is for your intended use, but if you intend to rely on visualizations as part of your regular report, you'll have to use the browser or [go third-party](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/), as this is not included in the language drivers. If you want to integrate just raw data and analysis, however, you definitely would want to leverage the language drivers, they are just as usable as a shelll, and you get to bring your favorite pre-existing tools to the party.